# sql update based on substring of values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update Tax area code field in table A based on description field in Table B.

Table B is as below. Description is(State-county-city-zipcode)

```
Code   Description
10001  TX-Denton-Frisco-75033
```

Table A has each field separated and does not have a county field and I need to match it at the minimum based on city,state and post code.

```
City    State  Post Code
Frisco  TX     75033
```

In below code I have matched it just based on Post code but I need a way to match it based on city,state and post code.

```
UPDATE Table A
SET [Tax Area Code] = b.[Code]
FROM Table B AS b
  JOIN Table A AS a 
ON a.[Post Code]=RIGHT(b.[Description],5)
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+specific+values+from+delimited+string+sql+server&oq=how+to+get+specific+values+from+delimited+string+sql+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.8719j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: use the LIKE operator in your join condition, specifying % for wildcard, that is    ON  b.[Description] LIKE a.[State] + '-%-' + a.[City] + '-' + a.[Post Code]

Comment: a word of caution: with any solution that splits the Description column into its components based on the hyphen as a delimiter, you will almost certainly get unexpected results if a county/city/post code in the Description column has a hyphen in it. If you have any influence on the DB design, you should redesign the Table B to separate the concatenated column into individual columns.

Comment: Can you help me with how I can split the hyphen delimited value to different columns?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data always follows the format State-county-city-zipcode, and none of those parts shall be missing, this would get you the `JOIN` you are after:

```
WITH TableB AS(
    SELECT 10001 AS Code,
           'TX-Denton-Frisco-75033' AS [Description]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10002 AS Code,
           'MA-Denton-South-Boston-01036' AS [Description]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10002 AS Code,
           'FL-Florida-State-Florida-79841' AS [Description]),
TableA AS(
    SELECT 'Frisco' AS City,
           'TX' AS [State],
           75033 AS PostCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'South-Boston' AS City,
           'MA' AS [State],
           01036 AS PostCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Florida' AS City,
           'FL' AS [State],
           79841 AS PostCode)
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.[Description] LIKE CONCAT(A.[state],'-%','-',A.City,'-',RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',A.PostCode),5));
```

How well that'll perform however... Now that's a totally different question (but not well I'd suggest).

Comment: Actually, @RichardII, it doesn't. See the update. It *did* however rely that `PostCode` had no leading zeroes, which I've now fixed (and assumed an American zip style)

Comment: it doesn't what?

Comment: Require that *"none of the parts contain a hyphen themselves"*, @RichardII .

Comment: that's good.   side note: in your 3rd data row, make up some other values for county and city.  Since "Florida" is a state, even though your example proves your point, it took me a while to wrap my head around what you were verifying :-)  Most US readers will experience the same mental hurdle I did.  Same thing with using "Florida-State" as the name of a county.   Even using  "abc-def" and "xyz" for city and county, respectively, would be preferable as sample data.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The query is however taking more time to execute.

Comment: Richard? And more time than what? (Note I did give a caveat on the performance, there's little you can do about this based on your requirement).

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
WITH TableB AS(
    SELECT 10001 AS Code,
           'TX-Denton-Frisco-75033' AS [Description]),
TableA AS(
    SELECT 'Frisco' AS City,
           'TX' AS [State],
           75033 AS PostCode)


SELECT * FROM TableA A
     JOIN TableB B ON 
     a.State=Substring(B.[Description],1, CHARINDEX('-', B.[Description],-1)-1)
     And a.City=Substring (B.[Description],PATINDEX('%' + A.city + '%',B.[Description]) , len(a.city))
     And  a.PostCode=RIGHT(b.[Description],5)
```